Correct term for "doneness" window?
When talking about cooking, what is the term used to refer to the window of time between undercooked, and overcooked? I've tried googling around and haven't found the correct one. I know some foods have a longer window than others, e.g., for roasting chicken breast, 1 minute, for thighs, longer, and for browned butter, the exact amount of time I look away from the saucepan.

The only thing that I can think of where someone MIGHT have given it a name was an episode of Good Eats about eggs, and Alton Brown had an RC car to talk about how slower cooking lowered the temperature for 'perfectly cooked' and made it less likely to overshoot.  (because although people say it's a temperature not a time... it's actually a state of being, and more about how you've altered the food with heat or chemicals)

First, the words "underdone" and "overdone" don't refer to time, rather they refer to temperature (or, perhaps more precisely time and temperature).  The phase between the two could be "done", "properly cooked", "safely cooked", "cooked to your liking"...there are perhaps more descriptors.
You will have to clarify what this has to do with roasting a chicken breast for 1 minute, which would likely place it in the "underdone" category.
Response to your update: I am not sure your clarification helps.  In many cases (take chicken thighs, which are very forgiving) one minute (or 5...or more) either way might not make a difference...in browning butter, it could be the difference between perfect and burnt.
To reiterate, it is about time + temperature.  I could prepare for you a chicken breast using a very low temperature water bath, and held over a long time that would be perfectly safe to eat ("done" could mean safe from pathogens), but that is not a product that people usually enjoy eating.
In the end, "done", or your window, is quite variable.  It is really about understanding ingredients, cooking methods, and the desired final outcome.

I think the OP thinks that there is a precise tipping point between "underdone" and "properly cooked", and another between "properly cooked" and "overdone" and thinks that, for a given meat, it always takes an exact amount of time between these two points.

Thank you, I'll update my question to be more accurate!

Most dishes have a target temperature range. For a chicken breast this could be 145F to 150F (depending on your preferences and risk profile). That means below 145 you would deem it undercooked and if its above 150F you would consider it overcooked.
So the "window" is the time it takes the temp to rise (in this example) from 145F to 150F. This time depends a lot on the thing you cook, the method and the target temperature.
If you throw a thin steak on a 600F+ grille, things will be moving very fast and your window is probably 20s or less. If you slow cook a huge chunk of roast beef at 210F in the oven, you have 10s of minutes.
Obviously the best choice for meats is a food thermometer. Keep an eye on it and pull it when you are at target (factoring in resting and post-cooking temperature rise). There are now good wireless thermometers where you can monitor the temperature on your phone and even set an alarm for the target temp.
One trick to determine the rise time is to look at the temp early in the process twice with one minute in between. Let's say you measure 70F and 80F, that means that you gained 10F in one minute and if your target is 130F you have around 5 minutes more to go. This is off course not exact, but it will be in the ballpark and give you a hint when to really start paying attention.
For things that you cannot easily stick a thermometer in, you just need to use your eyes, ears and nose. Again, If you are cooking on high heat, you need to stay close. If you are cooking with low or medium heat, you have more slack.

So if I got chicken up to 165, and then kept it there, it wouldn’t overcook?
